# ADB shell advanced commands info

Tags: android, shell, command, adb

I want to test some accessory for android phones and sometimes I need to control the phone. I find very useful to do it via adb. But I cann't anywhere find how to parametrize more advanced commands. For example calling command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:"012345678"`. Everything I was able to find is [ACTION_CALL documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL). There are no information about using it through command line. 
Is there any possibility to deduce which arguments i need to pass? Or does any reference manual exist for this purpose?

Comment: [Specification for <INTENT> arguments](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#IntentSpec)